# Eclipse PDT profiler

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Do you know if Eclipse PDT has a profiller plugin or not? Google didn't help me. :(

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have one, but you can still use http://xdebug.org/ with http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net

See here for more information: 
http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler